# ListBox SelectedIndex returning wrong value

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have an unbound ListBox populated with ListBox items with values such as:

```
new ListItem("Item1", "1")
new ListItem("Item2", "2")
new ListItem("Item3", "0")
new ListItem("Item4", "0")
new ListItem("Item5", "0")
```

A delete button should allow a user to delete a ListItem. However, whenever the user tries to delete an item with a value of zero, only the topmost 'zero' item is selected. In the example above, if 'Item5' was selected and delete was clicked, 'Item3' would be given the boot. Items with proper numbered values behave appropriately. Any idea why this might be happening, or did I answer my own question by typing it out (perhaps ASP.net can't differentiate between items with identical values)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Edit: To clarify, items with values of zero are removed differently than items with other values. Ie: If an item has a non-zero value, it is removed by value. If it has a value of zero, it is removed by it's ListBox index, but that index is always being returned as the index directly under the last non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You found the solution yourself. If you query the item by value, then the first item with that value will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing by value, remove by the index:

```
myDropDown.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListControl.Items.FindByText` and `ListControl.Items.FindByValue` are only going to return a single ListItem, and I assume the first one they find.

If you wanted to handle your situation with multiples of the same value, then you'd likely have to write some loop to find and remove them all.

Answer (score 0):

Your list items should have unique values. Asp.net only posts back the value selected for the list box so the server will be unable to tell which actual item it is so it just grabs the first match.

Comment: Edit: To clarify, items with values of zero are removed differently than items with other values. Ie:<br> If an item has a non-zero value, it is removed by value. If it has a value of zero, it is removed by it's ListBox index, but that index is always being returned as the index directly under the last non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looping through the collection and deleting the items, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListItem item = DropDownList1.Items[i];
    if (item.Value == "0")
        DropDownList1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```